# I need to arrive in the US before the Annotation Date

Tags: visas, usa, b1visa

I am a medical student, planning to do a 2-month-long clinical rotation in the USA. I applied for a B1 visa, provided a letter of invitation, stating that my clinical clerkships will last from May 6, 2024 till June 28th, 2024.
I just got a one-time visa, with an issue date of 22nd of September 2023, and an expiration date of 30th of June 2024. And annotation saying that I need to attend clerkships from May 6, 2024 till June 28th, 2024.

Unfortunately, my plans changed, I need to arrive in the US in April, 2024 to start my rotations.

Will that annotation date restrict me from entering the US? What should I do in such case, when I need to enter before the annotation date?

Comment: Do you have documents showing the change in plans?  Why did the schedule change?  In principle you should be fine if you can document a reasonable change in plans that isn't substantially different from what you described in your original application.

Comment: Please add the year to your dates (and format them in the same manor). That makes it easier to read and avoids misunderstandings.

Comment: @phoog, Yes I can ask the university professor to send the letter saying that my clerkships started earlier in April 2024. Do you think it will be enough? I don't want to risk flying to the border and being rejected ... Do you know any official sources, where I can get support?